# Replacing variable with command line argument in bash script

Tags: bash

I would like to call the script ./archive-it.sh with folder name ( like project1 ) without trailing / and expect to archive it, I am sure its pretty simple, as I am new to bash script i am stuck. Can someone help.

but currently i am getting error here

```
$target=$(echo "$1"-`date +%m-%d-%Y-%H_%M`)
```

Here is the script

```
!/bin/bash                        
######### archive-it.sh ############

echo "Argument  $1";
$target=$(echo "$1"-`date +%m-%d-%Y-%H_%M`)
tar -czvf $target.tar.gz  $1  

echo "####################################"
echo "ARCHIVE Successfully done at :"
echo "${target}" ;
```

also suggest me if its good to exclude .git folder, as I am taking only backup on a daily basis.

Answer (score 3):

To assign a variable, it's `target="something"`, then to access it you use `$target`

Also add quotes around $1 if the path contains spaces

```
echo "Argument  $1";

if [[ ! -d "${1}" ]]; then
    echo "Folder '$1' doesn't exists"
    exit 1
fi

#filter git files if you want
nogitfiles="$(find "${1}" -name * | grep -v .git)"

target="$(date +"$1-%m-%d-%Y-%H_%M")"
tar -czvf "${target}.tar.gz"  ${nogitfiles}  

echo "####################################"
echo "ARCHIVE Successfully done at :"
echo "${target}" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the echo at all:

```
target="$1$(date +%m-%d-%Y-%H_%M)"
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to assigning to `target`, not `$target`, and instead of concatenating `$1` and  the output of `date`, you can include `$1` in the format string for `date`:

```
target=$(date +"$1-%m-%d-%Y-%H_%M")
```